# Custom row actions on a specific category

Tags: categories

I am wondering if the row actions can be changed for a specific category. Like the `Uncategorized` category I want no "delete" link. Apparently in `class-wp-terms-list-table.php` line 336, Wordpress checks if the category is a default category. But I wan't to keep the `uncategorized` as a default.

Should I replace the `WP_Terms_List_Table` class myself by extending the `WP_List_Table` class?

Answer (score 1):

```
// remove the delete link for the specific category
function category_row_actions( $actions, $tag ) {
    if ( $tag->term_id == PROTECTED_TERM_ID ) unset( $actions['delete'] );
    return $actions;
}

// create the category if not excists (in case it's removed again in another theme)
if (file_exists (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php')) {
    require_once (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php'); 
    if ( ! get_cat_ID( 'One page' ) ) {
        $onepage_cat_id = wp_create_category( 'One page' );
        define( 'PROTECTED_TERM_ID', $onepage_cat_id );
    }
}

// make sure PROTECTED_TERM_ID is defined for the filter
if (!defined('PROTECTED_TERM_ID')) {
    $idObj = get_category_by_slug('one-page'); 
    $onepage_cat_id = $idObj->term_id;
    define( 'PROTECTED_TERM_ID', $onepage_cat_id );
}
if ( is_admin() ) {
    add_filter( 'category_row_actions', 'category_row_actions', 10, 2 );
}
```

Comment: Please post a solution, do not post links as answers. Links die, and if they do, the context of your answer is lost. Thank you

Comment: There you go, the code. The nazi attitude on stackexchange realy starting to piss me off. Not the comments, but the freaking downvotes on a good answer is realy childish.

Comment: An explanation to what the code does would be really useful and it is also recommended

Comment: A really good answer, hahaha. Please see [answer] and learn how a good answer should look like. Link only answers is **not** good answers. And please mind your language and attitude :-)

Comment: well, the answer wasn't wrong. like I said, the comments were justified. but other users might have the same question and might think the answer is sending them the wrong way because of the downvotes.